# Caption does not work with pspicture

Tags: captions, pspicture

I would like to include a caption below a tree drawn using pspictures. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-pdgr,pstricks,pst-pdf,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, left=2cm, bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

Blah blah.

\begin{figure}
    \begin{pspicture}(7,7)
        %\psgrid
        \psset{descarmA=1.2}
        \rput(2.5,4.5){\pstPerson[male]{A}}
        \rput(4.5,4.5){\pstPerson[female]{B}}
        \rput(2.5,2.5){\pstPerson[male, affected, belowtext={\small A1}]{C}}
        \rput(4.5,2.5){\pstPerson[female]{D}}
        \pstRelationship[descentnode=AB]{A}{B}
        \pstDescent{AB}{C}
        \pstDescent{AB}{D}
    \end{pspicture}
    \caption{figure}{figure text}
\end{figure}    

More blah.

\end{document}
```

Tree looks fine, however, caption is missing. There is no error message so I do not really have a clue as to what I am missing here. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure... but if you use a caption inside a figure environment , a simple `\caption{figure text}` would be enough. the caption package is needed for captions outside of float environments. Not inside them.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling your document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `auto-pst-pdf` and a pdflatex compilation, it works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-pdgr, pstricks, graphicx}%
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

Blah blah.

\begin{figure}
\centering \begin{pspicture}(7,7)
        \psset{descarmA=1.2}
        \rput(2.5,4.5){\pstPerson[male]{A}}
        \rput(4.5,4.5){\pstPerson[female]{B}}
        \rput(2.5,2.5){\pstPerson[male, affected, belowtext={\small A1}]{C}}
        \rput(4.5,2.5){\pstPerson[female]{D}}
        \pstRelationship[descentnode=AB]{A}{B}
        \pstDescent{AB}{C}
        \pstDescent{AB}{D}
    \end{pspicture}
    \caption{figure text}
\end{figure}

More blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you change anything in the code to make it work? Perhaps a different method of compilation?

Comment: @Werner: I only simplified the options of geometry (unrelated) and  removed the first argument  of `\caption`, but mainly, I replaced loading `pst-pdf` with `auto-pst-pdf`, and compiled with pdflatex, of course.

Comment: Thank you, Bernard. Replacing `pst-pdf` with `auto-pst-pdf` recovered the caption, and everything looks good.

Comment: @user3131944: This being said, I don't understand exactly why `pst-pdf` doesn't work, since `auto-pst-pdf` is supposed to be a wrapper for `pst-pdf`. I guess it sets some parameters so that it finally works.